# "Ghost" ContentControl stealing focus

Tags: wpf, focus, webbrowser-control

I have a tabbed control using a Template Selector, the correct template is selected which contains a WebBrowser component, when using the KeyBoard (Up/Down Arrows) the KeyBoardFocus toggels between the rest of the application and the web page.

Using snoop I can get the WebBrowser control to behave by setting the Focusable property of the containing ContentControl to false, however I can't figure out where/how to set the ContentControl property programmatically!

A snippet from snoop:

```
    PART_SelectedContentHost is from the Theme (Focusable == False)
    ContentControl (Focusable == **True**) [Where does this come from? It's "Content" is a ViewModel]
    ContentPresenter (Focusable == False) [Where does this come from?]
    WebPageView (My created component, Focusable == False) 
    ... (Focusable == False) 
    wbContent (Focusable == True)
```

I've tried using a targeted style resource in the ContentPresenter of PART_SelectedContentHost but with no luck.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try deriving from the tab control. Override the OnApplyTemplate method and find the contentcontrol by name. Once found change its property.